# how to delete a value from array in cookie array?

Tags: php, cookies, cakephp-3.0

I am using Cakephp 3.0.I am new in cookie concept. I have successfully created a cookie but i want to delete a value from cookie array.
Here is my code:-

```
enter code here
$cookiedata=
Array
(
[0] => 2
[1] => 1
)

$_GET['id'] = 2;

public function cartitems(){
    $cookiedata = $this->Cookie->read('ProductCartdata'); 
    $this->loadModel('Products');
    $query = $this->Products->find('all')->where(['id IN' =>$cookiedata]);
    $products = $query->hydrate(false)->toArray();
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            if(($key = array_search($_GET['id'], $cookiedata)) !== false) {
                    unset($cookiedata[$key]);
            } 
    $this->redirect(['controller'=>'test','action' => 'cartitems']);    
   }
        $this->set(compact('products','cookiedata'));
}
```

And i want that result:-

```
enter code here
Array
(
[0]=>1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read up on the Cookie-component in the documentation. There is a delete-method if you completely want to remove the data in your cookie:

[Cookie::delete($key)](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/cookie.html#Cake%5CController%5CComponent%5CCookieComponent::delete)

In your case it probably makes more sense to write over the existing data after looping:

```
$this->Cookie->write('ProductCartdata', $cookiedata);
```

Comment: why we again write cookie after deleting value from array

Comment: Well you want to update the Cookie don't you? The long winded answer is. When you read the cookie you get a copy of the data, but it stays the same in the cookie. If you update the data, e.g. by unsetting a key, then you have to update the cookie-data as well. Otherwise the next time you read from the cookie you will get the old data.

Comment: so according to you we again write cookie

Comment: Yes, we will update the cookie data to write our changes to the cookie again. You can think of your cookie as a kind of database. When you want your changes to stay you have to insert or update in the database. It's the same with data in a cookie.